# Jabref can use bibdesk filepointers?

Tags: bibtex, jabref, bibdesk

I am wondering whether there is a way to use BibDesk's filepointers? It has been suggested here that JabRef might not see anything that is specific to BibDesk:
[Will JabRef affect my BibDesk BibTeX file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/210799/will-jabref-affect-my-bibdesk-bibtex-file)

However this question is more about using BibDesk for something created in JabRef. What about the other way round? Does JabRef manipulate .bib files in a way that is intrusive to BibDesk usage of it?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Why not trying it with a backup copy and checking afterwards?

Comment: Good idea, will do that and report back. For now it seems that JabRef does not support bibdesk filepointers. What a shame..